# How to sanitize all form fields at once using node js

Tags: node.js, express, sanitize

I am processing form fields in node js using filter and sanitization process, all I want to do is at once all fields should be get sanitize and escape so I have used function and passing array to this, however it seems this logic is not working for me.

```
// function to sanitize all form fields
function check(array){
return  array.sanitize()
  .trim()
  .escape()
  .xss();
  
  }



    router.post('/register', function (req, res, next) {
     check([req.name, req.email, req.mobile,req.password]); // custom function to sanitize

// return error if found any issue in sanitiation and escape process     
      });
```

Comment: please share your approach that you have taken or methods that you have researched

Comment: @YashKumarVerma i have  written code  short code which u can notice it.

Comment: try express-validator